# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular15, angular-custom-validators

So, my issue is I am trying to build a custom validator on Angular 15, and I get an error message that tells this:

> Type 'Observable<{ titleAlreadyExists: boolean; } | null>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Type '{ titleAlreadyExists: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'."

This is my validator:

```
alreadyExistingTitle(alreadyExistingTitles: String[]): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
    return of(alreadyExistingTitles.includes(control.value))
      .pipe(
        map((result: boolean) =>
          result ? { titleAlreadyExists: true } : null
        )
      );
};
```

Comment: what if you change it to: `result ? { titleAlreadyExists: true } :  { titleAlreadyExists: false };` ?

Comment: Well, from what I understand from this official source (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators), the validator "takes an Angular control object and returns either null if the control value is valid or a validation error object."

Comment: I'm just going by the error message which says it can't be null. maybe try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the return type from `Observable<ValidationErrors>` to `Observable<ValidationErrors | null>`.

```
alreadyExistingTitle(alreadyExistingTitles: String[]): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return of(alreadyExistingTitles.includes(control.value)).pipe(
      map((result: boolean) => (result ? { titleAlreadyExists: true } : null))
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have the compile error anymore.